# Support vector machine problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, machine-learning, duality-theorems, karush-kuhn-tucker

The support vector machine problem is described below:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{min}_{w,b}&\frac{1}{2}||w||^2\\
\text{s.t.    }& v^{(i)}(w^\top u^{(i)}+b)\geq 1,i=1,...,m
\end{aligned}
$$
By writing its dual problem, We can get the optimal solution of the dual $\lambda^*$. But how can I derive the primal optimal solution from the dual optimal solution?